# Setting border left color dynamically depending on object value from a loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My goal is too reach a point where the border left of the cards looks like this:
[image: each card with a custom border left color]

The loop is as follows:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let office of searchItems" class="custom">
```

ideally id love to use string interpolation and have something like this for example:

```
style="border-left: 5px solid office.color"
```

using the "office" from the loop to get each cards office color

i resorted to setting the class="custom"

the css:

```
.custom {
  border-left: 5px solid var(--my-var);
  }
```

the JS:

```
 setStyle(value: string): void {
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('--my-var', value);
```

}

then in NgOnInit() I have:

```
for (let i in this.searchItems){
        document.body.style.setProperty('--my-var', this.searchItems[i].color);
        console.log(this.searchItems[i].color);

      }
```

this.searchItems looks like this:

[image: what i get from firebase]

but the cards border-left turns out to look like this even though the objects color is different :
[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors? If not, try to put the last block of code into ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: What is the meaning of the code in `ngOnInit()` ? you are setting color values to same variable in a loop !
`--my-var` will always contain the last color value.

You can use the inline styling like this - `style="border-left: 5px solid {{office.color}}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using below in the html template:

```html
[style.border-left]="'5px solid ' + office.color"
```